# Why is a hash map get/set considered to have O(1) complexity?

Tags: javascript, hashmap

Assume we have the following hash map class in Javascript:

```
class myHash {
    constructor() {
        this.list = [];
    }
    hash(input) {
        var checksum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            checksum += input.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return checksum;
    }
    get(input) {
        return (this.list[this.hash(input)]);
    }
    set(input, value) {
        this.list[this.hash(input)] = value;
    }
}
```

The `hash` function has a loop which has a complexity of `O(n)` and is called during getters and setters. Doesn't this make the complexity of the hash map `O(n)`?

Comment: What's a better hash function that doesn't use a for loop?, also `{}` on it's own is considered a HashMap, doesn't it? i'm trying to implement one myself.

Comment: @Joshl Your mind is in the right place, but the complexities you're confused about are totally different computations; the *lookup* is *usually* constant, while the *hash function* is not.

Comment: @Joshl normally when people talk about the complexity of an array or hash they are talking about how the behavior changes as the number of entries changes. In your class consider how long `get` takes when you have one entry and compare that to has long it takes when you have a million entries. One average they will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

When you're performing Big-O analysis you need to be very clear what the variables are. Oftentimes the *n* is left undefined, or implied, but it's crucial to know what exactly it is.

- Let's define *n* as the number of items in the hash map.

When *n* is the only variable under consideration then all of the methods are *O*(1). None of them loops over `this.list`, and so all operate in constant time *with respect to the number of items in the hash map*.

But, you object: there's a loop in `hash()`. How can it be *O*(1). Well, what is it looping over? Is it looping over the other items in the map? No. It's looping over `input`—but `input.length` is not a variable we're considering.

When people analyze hash map performance they normally ignore the length of the strings being passed in. If we do that, then **with respect to *n* hash map performance is *O*(1)**.

---

If you do care about string lengths then you need to add another variable to the analysis.

- Let's define *n* as the number of items in the hash map.
- Let's define *k* as the length of the string being read/written.

The hash function is *O*(*k*) since it loops over the input string in linear time. Therefore, `get()` and `set()` are also *O*(*k*).

Why don't we care about *k* normally? Why do people only talk about *n*? It's because *k* is a factor when analyzing the hash function's performance, but when we're analyzing how well the hash map performs we don't really care about how quickly the hash function runs. We want to know how well the hash map itself is doing, and none of its code is directly impacted by *k*. Only `hash()` is, and `hash()` is not a part of the hash map, it's merely an input to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the string size (`k`) does matter. (more precisely, the hash function complexity)

---

Assume:

- Get item use array index takes `f(n)` time
- The hash function takes `g(k)` time

then the complexity is `O( f(n)+g(k) )`.

We **know** that `g(k)` is `O(k)`, and if we **assume** `f(n)` is `O(1)`, the complexity becomes `O(k)`

Furthermore, if we **assume** the string size `k` would not great than a *constant* `c`, the complexity becomes `O(c)` which can be rewrite as `O(1)`.

---

So in fact, given your implementation, the `O(1)` is correct bound only if

- Get item use array index takes `O(1)`
- The string would not longer than a constant `c`

---

Notes

- Some hash function may itself be `O(1)`, like simply take the first character or the length.
- Whether get item use array index takes `O(1)` should be check, for example in javascript sparse array may take longer to access.